# Is it possible to be $100\%$ certain that any given outcome will happen?

Tags: probability

Recently I've been watching Rob Miles, an Artificial Intelligence Engineer, on YouTube.

I forget which specific video it was, but he claimed that since AI makes decisions based on probabilities of outcomes it will be impossible to know exactly what it will do since computers take things literally and a $0.0000000000001\%$ chance of failure is still a chance of failure.

What I'm wondering is if it is possible to ever reach $100\%$ certainty of an event, or if there will always be a tiny chance that something unexpected will happen

Edit : To refine my question, I'm wondering if there is any way to guarantee an outcome with a $0\%$ chance of failure, such as a machine that always flips a coin to heads. Would it be reasonably possible to assume we know all of the variables that go into a coin flip and conclude with $100\%$ certainty that we are correct?

Comment: I think this question needs to be more specific; the claim you seem to reference is likely more properly stated as "in this particular random system, there is a positive probability of every possible outcome" whereas your question is far broader - but it's not clear that the literal pure mathematics answer of "Yes, the axioms allow an event to have probability $1$" is at all what you're after. Could you perhaps narrow the scope of the question a bit? As it stands, I don't think you're likely to get a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

This mostly depends on the outcome.

For example with a dice roll in a casino in Las Vegas the event

$$
A= \text{the dice will show a number}
$$

will surely happen (here we consider a dice from a casino which has no rounded corners so it is impossible for it to stand on the corner),

$$
B=\text{the dice will show the number greater than 3}
$$

will happen roughly half the time ($50\%$ chance)

$$
C=\text{the dice will start to levitate}
$$

has zero chance of happening.

Comment: +1 for the beautiful choice of $C$.

Comment: If Chris Angel or David Blaine are around, you never know!

Comment: The Casino manager is smart enough not letting in those dudes...